# Map strings to numbers maintaining the lexicographic ordering

Tags: algorithm, string, sorting, function, mapping

I'm looking for an algorithm or function that is able to map a string to a number in such way that the resulting values correspond the lexicographic ordering of strings. Example:

```
"book" -> 50000
"car"  -> 60000
"card" -> 65000
"a longer string" -> 15000
"another long string" -> 15500
"awesome" -> 16000
```

As a function it should be something like: f(x) = y, so that for any x1 < x2 => f(x1) < f(x2), where x is an arbitrary string and y is a number.

If the input set of x is finite, then I could always do a sort and assign the proper values, but I'm looking for something generic for an unlimited input set for x.

Comment: I don't understand this. There is an infinite number of possible strings between "a longer string" and "another long string", so how can you guarantee unique values?

Comment: Do you have a maximum string length?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you require that `f` map to integers this is impossible.

Suppose that there is such a map `f`. Consider the strings `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, etc. Consider the values `f(a)`, `f(aa)`, `f(aaa)`, etc. As we require that `f(a) < f(aa) < f(aaa) < ...` we see that `f(a_n)` tends to infinity as `n` tends to infinity; here I am using the obvious notation that `a_n` is the character `a` repeated `n` times. Now consider the string `b`. We require that `f(a_n) < f(b)` for all `n`. But `f(b)` is some finite integer and we just showed that `f(a_n)` goes to infinity. We have a contradiction. No such map is possible.

Maybe you could tell us what you need this for? This is fairly abstract and we might be able to suggest something more suitable. Further, don't necessarily worry about solving "it" generally. YAGNI and all that.

Comment: with a maximum string length it may be possible however

Comment: @jk: yes, but question explicitly states "I'm looking for something generic, for an unlimited input set for x."

Comment: I supposed this would be the answer, but just wanted to be sure ... :-)
 The background: Actually I get some input sets of lets say 10000 strings each of maximum length 50, that is always different for each query. (That's why the unlimited input set.) Out of these strings I'd like to identify/group the similar ones and need a numeric value which matches the sort order for each separate input set. Solved the problem meanwhile, so thanks for your answer.

Comment: if you have a maximum length then the input set is limited (assuming a fixed alphabet) although probably very large. still it sounds like there is a better solution to the underlying problem anyway

Comment: @MicSim: What do you mean by "similar"? What do you need the numeric value for? Hashing?

Comment: By similar I mean equal. The numerical value, I would have needed it for sorting (the numerical value was expected by a 3rd party component, that i cannot change). But I solved my problem in another way, so that I don't have this requirement anymore.

Comment: @Jason: I like your answer, as it clearly shows: Proving an approach wrong or impossible lets you safely discard it and frees your mind for other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

As a corollary to [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914977/map-strings-to-numbers-maintaining-the-lexicograhic-ordering/1915030#1915030), if you can map your strings to rational numbers, such a mapping is very straightforward. If `code(c)` is the ASCII code of the character `c` and `s[i]` is the`i`th character in the string `s`, just sum like follows:

```
result <- 0
scale  <- 1
for i from 1 to length(s) 
  scale <- scale / 26
  index <- (1 + code(s[i]) - code('a'))
  result <- result + index / scale
end for
return result
```

This maps the empty string to 0, and every other string to a rational number between 0 and 1, maintaining lexicographical order. If you have arbitrary-precision decimal  floating-point numbers, you can replace the division by powers of 26 with powers of 100 and still have exactly representable numbers; with arbitrary precision binary floating-point numbers, you can divide by powers of 32.

Comment: Yes, and as you mention, the key here is that you absolutely have to have arbitrary-precision. Similar reasoning as in my answer shows why this must be the case. We have that `f(a_n) < f(b)` for all `n`. If there is a number `e > 0` such that `f(a_(n+1)) - f(a_n) > e` for all `n` then choose `N` so large that `N * e + f(a_1) > f(b)`. Then `f(a_N) = f(a_N) - f(a_(N-1) + f(a_(N-1)) - f(a_(N-2)) + f(a_(N-2)) - ... + f(a_1) > N * e + f(a_1) > f(b)`. So, there is no such `e` and we conclude that the `f(a_n)` must get arbitrarily close to each other and thus we require arbitrary-precision.

Comment: For a maximum string length L, is there such an e though right? In other words, is there a way to compute the maximum number of floating point bits you need to do the math under if you have an upper bound on your string length?

Answer (score 2):

what you are asking for is a a temporary suspension of the pigeon hole principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

The strings are the pigeons, the numbers are the holes.
There are more pigeons than holes, so you can't put each pigeon in its own hole.

Comment: It's not immediately evident why this is relevant if you're not familiar with the PHP (even with citation). You should at least map the concepts so someone else who stumbles on this post would find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You would be much better off writing a comparator which you can supply to a sort function. The comparator takes two strings and returns -1, 0, or 1. Even if you could create such a map, you still have to sort on it. If you need both a "hash" and the order, then keep stuff in two data structures - one that preserves the order, and one that allows fast access.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a [Radix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) is what you're looking for?

> A radix tree, Patricia trie/tree, or
>   crit bit tree is a specialized set
>   data structure based on the trie that
>   is used to store a set of strings. In
>   contrast with a regular trie, the
>   edges of a Patricia trie are labelled
>   with sequences of characters rather
>   than with single characters. These can
>   be strings of characters, bit strings
>   such as integers or IP addresses, or
>   generally arbitrary sequences of
>   objects in lexicographical order.
>   Sometimes the names radix tree and
>   crit bit tree are only applied to
>   trees storing integers and Patricia
>   trie is retained for more general
>   inputs, but the structure works the
>   same way in all cases.

[LWN.net also has an article describing this data structures use in the Linux kernel](http://lwn.net/Articles/175432/).

Answer (score 0):

I have post a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798824/what-lexicographic-order-means
As workaround you can append empty symbols with code zero to right side of the string, and use expansion from case II.

Without such expansion with extra empty symbols I' m actually don't know how to make such mapping....
But if you have a finite set of Symbols (V), then |V*| is eqiualent to |N| -- fact from Disrete Math.