# Sort anything lexicographically

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, azure-table-storage

I have this code which I think I found somewhere on the internet some years ago and it doesn't quite work.

The purpose is to take any string and from that create a string that is lexicographically sorted by a large number - because then inverse (descending) ordering can be achieved by subtracting the number from another even larger number.

```
private static BigInteger maxSort = new BigInteger(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("5335522543087813528200259404529154678271640415603227881439560533607051111046319775598721171814499900"));

public static string GetSortString(string str, bool descending)
{
    var sortNumber = new BigInteger(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str));

    if (descending)
    {
        sortNumber = maxSort - sortNumber;
    }

    return "$SORT!" + sortNumber.ToString().PadLeft(100, '0') + ":" + str;
}
```

The reason I need this is because I want to use it to insert as RowKey in Azure Table Storage which is the only way to sort in Table Storage. I need to sort any text, any number and any date, both ascending and descending.

Can anyone see the issue with the code or have any code that serves the same purpose?

The question is tagged with C# but of course this is not a question of syntax so if you have the answer in any other code that would be fine too.

**Example**

I want to convert any string to a number which is lexicographically sorted correctly - because if it's a number, then I can invert it and sort descending.

So for example, if I can convert:

```
ABBA    to 1234
Beatles to 3131
ZZ Top  to 9584
```

Then those numbers would sort them correctly ... and, if I subtract them from a large number, I would be able to invert the sort order:

```
10000 - 1234 = 8766
10000 - 3131 = 6869
10000 - 9584 = 0416
```

Of course, to support longer text input, I need to subtract them from a very large number, which is why I use the very large BigInteger.

**Current output from this code**

```
ABBA:    $SORT!0000000000000000000000018296156958359617:ABBA
Beatles: $SORT!0000000009111360792640460912278748069954:Beatles
ZZ TOP:  $SORT!0000000000000096715522885596192519618650:ZZ TOP
```

As you can see, the longest text gets the highest number. I have also tried to add padding immediately on the input `str`, but that didnt help either.

**Answer**

The accepted answer worked. For descending sort order, the "BigInteger" trick from above could be used.

There is some limitation as to how long the sortable string can be.

Here is the final code:

```
private static BigInteger maxSort = new BigInteger(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("5335522543087813528200259404529154678271640415603227881439560533607051111046319775598721171814499900"));

public static string GetSortString(string str, bool descending)
{
    BigInteger result = 0;
    int maxLength = 42;

    foreach (var c in str.ToCharArray())
    {
        result = result * 256 + c;
    }

    for (int i = str.Length; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        result = result * 256;
    }

    if (descending)
    {
        result = maxSort - result;
    }

    return "$SORT!" + result;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean "lexicographically sorted by a large number"? Could you, please, provide some *examples*? For instance, what is the desired result for `"1443235"` and why? Isn't it `"1233445"`?

Comment: Yes I will update the question with an example. Thank you.

Comment: I still don't understand the need to map them to integers - there are plenty of ways to sort strings lexicographically (in ascending or descending order) in C# already, and `RowKey` properties are, as you say, _text_

Comment: Please do share! I hope I am overlooking something obvious. I don't need to sort things in C# though, I need to create strings that are already sorted correctly so I get them out of Table Storage in the order that I want.

Comment: @NielsBrinch: Are you jumping through these hoops just to be able to sort some strings in descending order? - because there are simpler ways to do that.

Comment: Please do share. But imagine the scenario being 1 million rows inserted in table storage and I want to get them out in the right order without having to get all of them out in memory first.

Comment: what is the value for `maxSort` ?

Comment: It's a large number (first line in the code): new BigInteger(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("5335522543087813528200259404529154678271640415603227881439560533607051111046319775598721171814499900"));

Comment: I asked a very similar question to yours: [Map strings to numbers maintaining the lexicographic ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1914977/44522). And  the answer is a proof that it is impossible. Maybe you should look further into Azure Table Storage and look for other ways to achieve what you need.

Comment: I am fairly sure there are no other solutions as this has been discussed at some length by others for years. Thank you for the question, you are indeed right that it is very similar - except there is no requirement to invert it. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were looking for a way to give a a value to any string so that you could sort them accordingly to the number and get the same result as above you can't. The reason is that strings don't have any length limit. Because you can always add a char to a string and thereby get a larger number even through it should have a lower lexicographical value.

If they have a length limit you can do something like this

pseudo code

```
bignum res = 0;
maxLength = 42;
for (char c : string)
  res = res * 256 + c
for (int i = string.length; i < maxLength; i++)
  res = res *256
```

If you want to optimize a bit, the last loop could be a lookup table. If your only using a-z, the times 256 could reduced to 26 or 32.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not looking for a way to sort. Looking at your pseudo code. I am happy with a length limit of string and also put a limit of 100 characters in my own try. You think this would work - and also when inversed?

Comment: Is the * in your pseudo code meant as a multiplier? Asking because some languages use it as some sort of reference indicator.

Comment: Should I do something with strings that are too short? Pad them with 0s? Before or after?

Comment: @NielsBrinch no the 2nd loop takes care of that. Hmm that should be 256-c if reversing.

Comment: The code works for ascending, but not descending. But maybe it was not clear to me where it should go 256 - c. Even though it must be in the first loop because thats the only place there is a c.

Comment: Actually the "subtract from bigint" seems to work for descending. I will have to do some more testing.

Comment: It works. I suggest you remove the first part of your answer so people don't think that part is somehow relevant to the question.